# Is Tony in love with Gina?

Tags: analysis, character, scarface

Throughout Brian DiPalma's 1983 classic, [Scarface](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086250/), Tony Montana has an odd relationship with his sister Gina. His attitude toward her ranges from overprotective to jealous to generous, and just about any conceivable emotion in between.

At those moments when Tony's jealousy and overprotective nature are exposed (seeing Gina go into the bathroom with a guy, when he shoots Manny, etc.), it appears that Tony has passionate feelings for his sister stronger than two siblings should share.

**Simply put: is Tony in love with his sister, Gina?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think he's more in love with the *idea* of an innocent Gina, the little girl he used to know before he went to jail. He is obsessed with keeping her *pure*, since everything else in his life is steeped in sin. So when he catches her doing adult things, like her encounter in the club and having a secret affair with his best friend, he loses his mind as he sees her as the only good thing in his life.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Tony was obsessed with Gina. He just had the image of her as a little girl and didn't want her to be like him, so what Manny told Gina in the movie was true that Tony was like a father to her, protecting her and such. Tony was high on cocaine when he killed Manny, if he wasn't he probably would have been shocked sure but he wouldn't have killed Manny because later on when Sosa's army attacks Tony's mansion, you see Tony regretting what he did to Manny saying "oh fuck Manny, how'd I do that?" and then when Gina is shot and killed he says "I love Manny and I love you too you know?", so that kind of tells you Tony didn't have an incest obsession with Gina, but a fatherly type of love for Gina. He was protective yeah, but very overprotective.

Answer (score 1):

Tony knew that they already have the sexual relationship but when his mother cries in-front of him , he become angry that his mom told that he had made her exactly as him...so he killed many...but later due to sorrow and stress Gina thinks that he is saving her for sex....that is why after death he cries for Gina.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the point is that Tony is unable to deal with his sister having a romantic relationship with another man, because Tony is unable to love women, as he sees them as objects. The thing he is afraid of most, is she'll end up with a guy like Tony (Manny).

She deserves a guy "better" than Tony, but Tony is the guy that Gina sees as her role model. When she ends up falling in love with Manny, Tony kills him because he can't stand to see her sister with this scum (even though Manny has more loyalty than Tony), which is a deep down denial that Tony believes that he is really scum himself.

Tony sees Elvira as a status to be obtained, and it's how he assumes all men see women.

And YES, Tony does want to bang his sister. In his delusion, she is the perfect, pure woman, who no man is worthy of. Tony wishes he could be the guy pure enough to deserve her (his twisted sense of morality), but he knows he isn't.

Answer (score -1):

I do believe he is in love with his little sister. I think in his mind he's just being the protective older brother, but he takes it way too far. Gina even brings this up before she dies. His possessiveness and his need to control her stems from his own desires. He can't stand for another man to even look at her, because deep down he wants her for himself.

Comment: Why should we trust a zombie killed by the guy you say is incestuous?